# Выборка в ClickHouse

Tags: sql, база-данных, выборка, clickhouse

Я смотрел [Базы данных. ClickHouse. Колоночные СУБД](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36Qql0DE4tk&t=1268s).

Там на [слайде](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1-Yy2RBqFomhMpckWrFUehZBRR0ZH6MDCk5kFxOEqtDw/edit#slide=id.g72338cd894_0_67)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
( на видео это участки `21:15`-`28:20` и `25:41`-`28:20`)
разбирается, что попадет в результат запроса

```
CounterID In ['a', 'h']
```

**Вопрос:**
Почему результат получается именно такой как показано на слайде?
Или если быть точнее, то почему в результаты выборки проходят значения не соответствующие условию выборки?
(*в него попадают значения `b.1`,`b.2`,`g.1`,`g.2` с **CounterID** равным `b` и `g` и  не соответствующие условию*)

---

**Ссылки:**

- Видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36Qql0DE4tk&t=1268s
- Презентация: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1-Yy2RBqFomhMpckWrFUehZBRR0ZH6MDCk5kFxOEqtDw/edit#slide=id.g72338cd894_0_67

Comment: С выборкой все понятно?.. Я поправил и дополнил вопрос, т.к. в нашу сторону уже минусы полетели. Проверьте правильно ли я отразил значение вопроса?

Comment: Они попадают не в результат выборки, а в «гранулы» в которых CH будет делать выборку.

Answer (score -1):

Ответ кроется в следующем факте:
Минимальная извлекаемая единица данных - это гранула
Соответственно данные можно извлечь только гранулами.
Невозможно извлечь какое-то одно конкретное значение

Данный факт является объяснением всего что происходило на том слайде

Соответственно при запросе `CounterID In ['a', 'h']`
мы извлекаем гранулы: `[a.1, a.2, a.3, g.1, h.2]`

Смысл прост: мы выбираем все гранулы в которых `CounterID` равен либо `a`, либо `h`.

- С гранулами `[a.1, a.2]` надеюсь все понятно. 
  Там все значения соответствуют условию
- С гранулой `[a.3]` уже есть проблемы, поскольку она уже содержит в себе значения b.1,b.2
  А входят они в нее ровно только потому что мы не можем разделить гранулу и эта гранула соответствует условию выборки, поскольку она содержит значения с первичным ключам `a`
- с гранулой `g.1` похожая история, только наоборот
  в нее под самый конец вошли значения с ключом `h`, после чего данная гранула начала соответствовать условию выборки, но как-то сепарировать их от значений, которые были в данной грануле до **мы не можем**
- с гранулой `h.2` все чисто...там все значения содержат ключ `h` и заканчиваются аккурат к границе гранулы.

**Соответственно, мы выбираем все ГРАНУЛЫ, в которых есть ХОТЯ БЫ ОДНО ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, подходящее условию.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]